# How do I fix player positioning being off in Node.JS and Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm making a multiplayer game and the way I am making player movement is whenever you click a key, that key is sent to all the other users in your lobby. They then change your position according to what key you clicked. For example if I clicked the 'W' key then it would be sent to everyone and they would all move my character forward. The reason I'm doing it this way is to save bandwidth and try to eliminate a lot of lag. However, this causes 2 problems. One of them being that the clients don't receive that keycode at the same time. Whenever I call Date.now() on JavaScript when I receive that key it is about 1 off from other clients. This will cause about a 3 pixel gap in between where it's supposed to be. I've already implemented Delta time so it looks the same on all framerates. The second problem is that I am highly trying to avoid hosting player positions on server unless necessary. This is a problem because if the players need to get the same position, the server can't give clients that data. To fix this, I made it so when I need a new position update, whether it's because I wasn't on the tab and missed a key or because my positioning is off, it would ask another client for their existing players positions. This solution only works when at least one client, excluding the person who asked, is on the tab.

I've tried using a setInterval to continuously change the players positions and match them up, but that made the players clip all over the place. I've also tried hosting the player positions on the server but it lags a lot and it won't be good if I have 1000 people on a server.

For client side I use p5js

This is the code that sends the server the key I clicked, whenever I click a key:

```
function keyPressed() {
  if (gameStarted) {
    if (keyCode === 122) {
      return false;
    }
    if (currentKey.key != null) {
      //if (currentKey.on == false || currentKey.key != keyCode) {
        currentKey.key = keyCode;
        currentKey.on = true;
        socket.emit('newKeyCode',{key:currentKey.key,on:true});

      //}
    }
    else {
      currentKey.key = keyCode;
      currentKey.on = true;
      socket.emit('newKeyCode',{key:currentKey.key,on:currentKey.on});
    }
  }
}

function keyReleased() {
  if (gameStarted) {
    if (currentKey.key != null) {
      currentKey.key = keyCode;
      currentKey.on = false;
      socket.emit('newKeyCode',{key:currentKey.key,on:currentKey.on});
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code that is on the server for whenever I tell the server I pressed a new key:

```
socket.on('newKeyCode',function(data) {
  var lobby = LOBBY_DATA[PLAYER_LIST[socket.id].lobby];
  if (lobby != null && lobby != undefined) {
    //console.log(data);
    for (var i in lobby.players) {           
      SOCKET_LIST[lobby.players[i].id].emit('newKeyFromClient', {id:socket.id,name:PLAYER_LIST[socket.id].user,key:data.key,on:data.on});
    }
  }
});
```

And this is the client code that is ran when I get a new key from the server:

```
socket.on('newKeyFromClient',function(data) {
  socket.emit('receivedKey');
  console.log(Date.now());
  if (gameStarted) {
    changePlayerDirections(data.key, data.on, data.id);
  }
});
```

My goal is to make it so the clients both have the exact same player positioning, you can see for yourself at [My game](http://multiclassics.com/kingofthekrystals/login/). Once you register and login, click on the Play button in the top left, then duplicate 3 more tabs so you have a total of 4, create a new lobby on one of them and split your computer screen into 4 windows so you can see all of them at once, then join your lobbies on all the windows. Once there are 4 people in your lobby, click Start Game on your host window. This will put you into the game where you can move around with WASD and you'll see it move on the other clients screens. However, it's gonna be a bit off and that's the problem. I want it to be dead on and exact on every single screen.

EDIT:
Sorry if there are rapid changes in the server, I'm working on it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have already read articles on multiplayer: using UDP or TCP, frame rates for sending receiving datas, simulating game on server and syncing, etc. I will just write my experience.

I made a multiplayer game exactly similar way (using node.js and socket.io sending key events). Testing on LAN was all smooth. Then I tested it on wifi and it was a disaster. Then I send position, and they started jumping around. Bigger problem was it got way random and slower to update.

I read few articles on multiplayer and decided to use UDP to update position. It got fast and on wifi it was negligibly jumpy. Now deploying on server, port started changing. I learned about NAT traversals and stuffs, but it was too vast to implement myself. One thing I found was, at least the port from server was constant : '3000'.

Then I revert back to TCP and tried simulating game on server and sync with client. I send key events and on third frame synced position from server to client. Not much better and I still had to sync game logic. Thats where I stopped.

There is a logic I want to try but have been lazing around. Send key event to server using UDP, simulate on server and sync using TCP but this time using timestamp to determine which value to prevail (server or client). And reducing the data to send, using array of integer only.